# WKWebView button not showing

Tags: ios, button, indexing, overlapping, wkwebview

I'm making a WKWebView app, and I'd like to display a button that when clicked will take me to the homepage of my website. The WebView takes up the whole screen, and when I place a button in the Main.Storyboard file it doesn't show up (I think it's because the webview overlaps it or something).

Here's my ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  FLWebView
//
//  Created by Steve Richey on 11/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Float Mobile Learning. Shared under an MIT license. See license.md for details.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
// Required for calls to UIWebView and WKWebView to "see" our categories
#import "UIWebView+FLUIWebView.h"
#import "WKWebView+FLWKWebView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

/*
 * Called when the view has completed loading. Time to set up our WebView!
 */
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Check if WKWebView is available
    // If it is present, create a WKWebView. If not, create a UIWebView.
    if (NSClassFromString(@"WKWebView")) {
        _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: [[self view] bounds]];
    } else {
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: [[self view] bounds]];
    }

    // Add the webView to the current view.
    [[self view] addSubview: [self webView]];

    // Assign this view controller as the delegate view.
    // The delegate methods are below, and include methods for UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, and WKUIDelegate
    [[self webView] setDelegateViews: self];

    // Ensure that everything will resize on device rotate.
    [[self webView] setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [[self view]    setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    // Just to show *something* on load, we go to our favorite site.
    [[self webView] loadRequestFromString:@"http://LiftedFeed.com/"];

}

/*
 * Enable rotating the view when the device rotates.
 */
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

/*
 * This more or less ensures that the status bar is hidden for this view.
 * We also set UIStatusBarHidden to true in the Info.plist file.
 * We hide the status bar so we can use the full screen height without worrying about an offset for the status bar.
 */
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate Methods

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that do not have WKWebView when the UIWebView requests to start loading a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls shouldStartDecidePolicy, which is a shared delegate method.
 * Returning YES here would allow the request to complete, returning NO would stop it.
 */
- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType
{
    return [self shouldStartDecidePolicy: request];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that do not have WKWebView when the UIWebView starts loading a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls didStartNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad: (UIWebView *) webView
{
    [self didStartNavigation];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that do not have WKWebView when a URL request load failed.
 * Note that it just calls failLoadOrNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webView: (UIWebView *) webView didFailLoadWithError: (NSError *) error
{
    [self failLoadOrNavigation: [webView request] withError: error];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that do not have WKWebView when the UIWebView finishes loading a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls finishLoadOrNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView
{
    [self finishLoadOrNavigation: [webView request]];
}

#pragma mark - WKWebView Delegate Methods

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view wants to start navigation.
 * Note that it calls shouldStartDecidePolicy, which is a shared delegate method,
 * but it's essentially passing the result of that method into decisionHandler, which is a block.
 */
- (void) webView: (WKWebView *) webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction: (WKNavigationAction *) navigationAction decisionHandler: (void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy)) decisionHandler
{
    decisionHandler([self shouldStartDecidePolicy: [navigationAction request]]);
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view starts loading a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls didStartNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webView: (WKWebView *) webView didStartProvisionalNavigation: (WKNavigation *) navigation
{
    [self didStartNavigation];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view fails to load a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls failLoadOrNavigation, which is a shared delegate method,
 * but it has to retrieve the active request from the web view as WKNavigation doesn't contain a reference to it.
 */
- (void) webView:(WKWebView *) webView didFailProvisionalNavigation: (WKNavigation *) navigation withError: (NSError *) error
{
    [self failLoadOrNavigation: [webView request] withError: error];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view begins loading a URL request.
 * This could call some sort of shared delegate method, but is unused currently.
 */
- (void) webView: (WKWebView *) webView didCommitNavigation: (WKNavigation *) navigation
{
    // do nothing
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view fails to load a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls failLoadOrNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webView: (WKWebView *) webView didFailNavigation: (WKNavigation *) navigation withError: (NSError *) error
{
    [self failLoadOrNavigation: [webView request] withError: error];
}

/*
 * Called on iOS devices that have WKWebView when the web view finishes loading a URL request.
 * Note that it just calls finishLoadOrNavigation, which is a shared delegate method.
 */
- (void) webView: (WKWebView *) webView didFinishNavigation: (WKNavigation *) navigation
{
    [self finishLoadOrNavigation: [webView request]];
}

#pragma mark - Shared Delegate Methods

/*
 * This is called whenever the web view wants to navigate.
 */
- (BOOL) shouldStartDecidePolicy: (NSURLRequest *) request
{
    // Determine whether or not navigation should be allowed.
    // Return YES if it should, NO if not.

    return YES;
}

/*
 * This is called whenever the web view has started navigating.
 */
- (void) didStartNavigation
{
    // Update things like loading indicators here.
}

/*
 * This is called when navigation failed.
 */
- (void) failLoadOrNavigation: (NSURLRequest *) request withError: (NSError *) error
{
    // Notify the user that navigation failed, provide information on the error, and so on.
}

/*
 * This is called when navigation succeeds and is complete.
 */
- (void) finishLoadOrNavigation: (NSURLRequest *) request
{
    // Remove the loading indicator, maybe update the navigation bar's title if you have one.
}

@end
```

Comment: [self view] addSubview:webview]] does in fact place this view at the top of the z-order.  Create an outlet to your button (e.g. myButton) then call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myButton].

Comment: After attempting to add the button and failing, i removed all of the new code i had added for it and tried to launch the app. Now i'm facing an error that looks simple, but is starting to give me a headache. After launching the app, the app goes through the launch screen and right before the main view is loaded, the app pauses and highlights these lines in green
[[self view] addSubview: [self webView]];      and on the right says thread:1 breakpoint 1.1
the bottom box displays
self ViewController * 0x7fa79041e090 0x00007fa79041e090
_webView UIView * 0x7fa7906577a0 0x00007fa7906577a0